# Objective C - Constraints return after being removed

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've added constraints to views using Interface Builder.
Later in run, I need to remove them and add new ones.
Here is how I update constraints :

```
    for (UIView *view in _fromProduitView.subviews) {
                 [view removeConstraints:view.constraints];
            for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in _fromProduitView.constraints) {
                if ([[constraint firstItem] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                    [_fromProduitView removeConstraint:constraint];
                }
            }
     }
     [_fromProduitView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_fonctionLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_fromProduitView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
     [_fromProduitView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_fonctionLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_fromProduitView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:16]];

     [_fromProduitView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_artisanNameLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_fromProduitView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
     [_fromProduitView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_artisanNameLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_fonctionLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:8]];

     [_fromProduitView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_supplierAccrocheLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_fromProduitView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
     [_fromProduitView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_supplierAccrocheLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_artisanNameLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:8]];
```

At this point, I log the constraints of the view `_fromProductView` which is the superview :

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7fdc2df84cc0>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2dfa2d40 UIView:0x7fdc2dfa59e0.height == 0>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2db32320 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4730.centerX == UIView:0x7fdc2dfa59e0.centerX>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2e9f3210 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4730.top == UIView:0x7fdc2dfa59e0.leading + 16>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2df84960 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfb0d60.centerX == UIView:0x7fdc2dfa59e0.centerX>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2cff0b90 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfb0d60.top == UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4730.bottom + 8>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2e9f38b0 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4c30.centerX == UIView:0x7fdc2dfa59e0.centerX>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2e9f4390 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4c30.top == UILabel:0x7fdc2dfb0d60.bottom + 8>
)
```

Which is the way I want, But the problem is, later the contraints I've removed come back and conflict with the ones I've create which the results the views to disappear :

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7fdc2b5f7460>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2dfa2d40 UIView:0x7fdc2dfa59e0.height == 0>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2e9f3210 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4730.top == UIView:0x7fdc2dfa59e0.leading + 16>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2df84960 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfb0d60.centerX == UIView:0x7fdc2dfa59e0.centerX>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2e9f38b0 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4c30.centerX == UIView:0x7fdc2dfa59e0.centerX>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2dfa2de0 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4730.centerX == UIView:0x7fdc2dfa59e0.centerX - 8>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2dfa2e30 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4730.leading == UILabel:0x7fdc2dfb0d60.leading>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2dfa2ed0 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfb0d60.top == UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4730.bottom + 2>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2dfa2f70 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4c30.leading == UILabel:0x7fdc2dfb0d60.leading>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2dfa2fc0 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4c30.top == UILabel:0x7fdc2dfb0d60.bottom>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2cff0b90 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfb0d60.top == UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4730.bottom + 8>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2e9f4390 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4c30.top == UILabel:0x7fdc2dfb0d60.bottom + 8>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdc2db32320 UILabel:0x7fdc2dfa4730.centerX == UIView:0x7fdc2dfa59e0.centerX>
)
```

So mainly, What I don't understand is how to delete constraints permanently and how to update view when new ones are added

Comment: If you remove all constraints, may be you shouldn't add them in IB from the beginning?

Comment: Try to deactivate the constraints first and then apply new ones. you can simple deactivate the constraint by setting `active` property to `NO`.

Comment: I am not removing all the constraints, the `superView` contains other views beside those. Beside, this scenario is only happening when some 'rare' conditions are met.

Comment: @AsadAli I'll try that.

Comment: Still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create outlets for the constraints of which you want to delete. Try deactivating your constraints instead deleting like below:

```
yourconstraint.active = YES;
```

After that assign the new constraints to the view programmatically and call the below method on the required view:

`[self updateConstraints]`;

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.